# how to manually authenticate user in asp.net windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have an Intranet application with Windows Authentication. Everything works fine. However, for some sensitive operations (it could be approving AP check, or grading a student) I need to get user's id and password. The goal is to prevent somebody walking to unattended terminal, and generally for non-repudiation. Trivial with forms authentication - but I can't figure out how to do it with Windows authentication.

I don't think it matters, but it's MVC application and authentication is done against Active Directory

Comment: How is IIS configured? (as in: windows, forms, anon, etc)

Comment: IIS in general allows all of above. This particular application is configured for windows authentication. as I said, automatic windows authentication works as it supposed to. 
What I can't figure out is how to manually "force" the user to authenticate. I played with WindowsIdentity, WindowsPrincipal, etc - but it shows how to define roles and provide granular access to resources - which is different from what I am trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, server application needs to issue HTTP Status Code 401 to tell client for authentication information. However, in case of windows authentication, once user is authenticated, the token is cached by client system or browser and used subsequently whenever needed. So in your case, even if you issue 401, client will send the same token again - so your main problem of abusing unattended terminal will not get solved (as user already logged in there into the system).

One of the way could be simulate forms authentication from the application - i.e. on sensitive operations, prompt user for his/her windows password again (note that you will be already having user's name(identity) if you are using windows authentication) and then re-validate that password using active directory API (or logon user windows API).

Personally, I feel that you are trying to solve the problem at server which is wrong end - I would rather have a IT policy that prohibits unlocked unattended terminals - either user should lock the workstation or have a password protected screen saver. Typically, these things can be somewhat enforced via group policy.

Comment: Yes - I played with AD APis (from http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Forms-Authentication-Active-Directory.aspx ) and it seems to be working.
I significantly simplified the use case... In reality the main purpose is non-repudiation. In other words, say, if the stock broker makes a trade, we need some audit log that name/password was entered at the time of the trade. Our industry is different, and situation is much more complex - but this "e-signature" requirement is driven by regulatory compliance; not just IT policy implementation.

Comment: I just return error 401 in the middleware and I always get windows authentication popup. but somehow I can't get authorized with correct username and password once I return the error401 in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

In my webforms app I've got one page set as only allowing Windows Auth and no others, and then to get the username (since they have to have already done the 401 auth procedure via the browser) I get their username like thus:

```
string username = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

and then I can query the Membership provider to get the user information from the infrastructure.

Or are you trying to manually do the 401 auth process?

> how to manually authenticate user in asp.net windows authentication